# How to change the default driver used for an external screen

Tags: xorg, drivers, display

I'm having trouble setting up an external DisplayLink screen in Fedora 20.

I've found someone who seems to be having exactly the same problem as me and his solution:

```
If you are using "displaylink" for the Xorg driver module, switch it to fbdev.
```

I'm trying to figure out how to do this. I've been searching around, apparently Fedora doesn't use an `xorg.conf` file anymore as it determines the configuration every time X is started.

I've downloaded ArandR and looked in the system configs as well, I couldn't find a way to manually assign a driver to this device (DVI-1-0 is the DisplayLink screen).

I tried generating my own xorg.conf as well using `Xorg :l -configure` and get told:

```
Fatal server error:
(EE) Server is already active for display 0
```

I can't seem to be able to generate an xorg.conf. Solutions to this problem recommend shutting down my desktop manager, which leads to chaotic results in the following terminal, forcing me to hard-reboot.

My question is: How can I assign a specific driver to the external screen, instead of the default one? Can this be done without an `xorg.conf`?

I use MATE desktop, Fedora 20.

Answer (score 2):

Fedora doesn't use an `xorg.conf` by default as this allows the X server to probe for its configuration. It assumes that the X server knows best.

However, if you add an `xorg.conf` it will simply override the probed values.

A minimal example might be:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Default"
    Monitor "Monitor1"
    Device "Device1"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "Monitor1"
EndSection


Section "Device"
    Identifier "Device1"
    Driver "fbdev"
EndSection
```